# Case sensitive anchor issue on Chrome

Tags: javascript, anchor, typeerror

Case sensitive links don't work on chrome. If name of anchor is link#Anchor1 will not work, and link#anchor1 will.

I went ahead and searched for solution and found .toLowerCase() function.
Now I have a new issue I couldn't fix: Uncaught TypeError: anchorEl.offset is not a function

```
  $(window).load(function()
  {
    var hashVal= window.location.hash.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    var anchorEl = $("a[name='"+hashVal+"']").toLocaleString().toLowerCase().split(',');
    var elOffset = anchorEl.offset();
    var offsetTop = elOffset.top;
    $(document).scrollTop( offsetTop - 200);
    console.log(offsetTop);

  });
```

It partially works on Firefox, except for the offset value, either +200 or -200 it won't make a difference (it's behind the navigation bar) but it doesn't move a inch on Chrome.

Comment: You do realise that ```anchorEl``` is an array with the code that you've provided? ...

Comment: try this: var anchorEl = $("a[name='"+hashVal.toLocaleString().toLowerCase()+"']");

Comment: @Piyushaggarwal Thanks. The error is now: TypeError: elOffset is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below. First select all the `a` elements with `name` attribute and then filer with comparing to windows hash.

```
var anchorEl = $("a[name]").toArray().filter(function(a) {
    return $(a).attr('name').toLowerCase() == hashVal.toLowerCase();
});
var elOffset = $(anchorEl).offset();
```

Checkout code below. It's scrolls to 300px;

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var hashVal = "Action"; //window.location.hash.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  var anchorEl = $("a[name]").toArray().filter(function(a) {
    return $(a).attr('name').toLowerCase() == hashVal.toLowerCase();
  });
  if (anchorEl.length > 0) {
    var elOffset = $(anchorEl).offset();
    var offsetTop = elOffset.top;
    $(document).scrollTop(offsetTop - 200);
    console.log(offsetTop);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top: 300px;">
  <a href="#" name="action"> action </a>
</div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 300px;">
  <a href="#" name="action2"> action2 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of the native filter function associated with an `Array`, however, to correct your statement, it won't give an "exact element", rather it will return a new jQuery object, which can be a number of elements.

Comment: I like the edit, however, be careful as with some versions of jQuery the value of `a` may be an index rather than a jQuery object.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V, Yes it can possibly give multiple objects but I've checked and found that jquery will always return `offset()` of first element from the list. So it will not show any error.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V, thanks for advice. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: That's very true, but as stated, with jQuery(hardly ever use it anymore), this example actually doesn't work with the most recent version of jQuery, I *believe* you have to use `$(this)`, or store get the object at index `x` in some other fashion, I'm sure there's plenty of ways to do it...

Comment: @Karan Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: @staminna wrapped code with `if (anchorEl.length > 0) {` so if no such `hash` found then it will not throw an error.

Comment: @Karan the hash exists, elOffset is undefined , the error is  not thrown anymore but no scroll.

Comment: Sure, It will be my pleasure.